# -webkit-background-clip:text not work in Android phone

Tags: android, css, webkit

it seems that the css3 -webkit-background-clip:text, don`t work in the Android phone with webkit core blowers. Because I want to make the text with  the gradient effect, the -webkit-background-clip:text  just work well in PC. is it really like so? Is there somebody to  help with this issue, thanks!

Comment: you should at least provide the info which android version you are talking of

Comment: Are you using the unprefixed version as well? Only 2.3 needs a prefixed verison. http://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar case on a Android Lollipop device. I had used `-webkit-background-clip:text` on a `<button>` tag. It worked well in chromium browser, and it even worked on a Android Marshmallow device. But the same clip effect won't appear on that lollipop device. After hours, fixed it by changing `<button>` tag to a `<div>` and it worked. Not sure if this could be your case, if not, post your css code.